# How do I verify an api's access to my api?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, architecture, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

I'm building an api, which we'll call **CommonApi**, that other API's will consume. For this example, let's assume we have an application with a front-end using `superNewTrendyFrameworkThatsTheBest.js` and a WebApi backend, which we'll call **AppApi**. We are using MS Identity, provided by our IDP.

So, the app will use its own api, AppApi, to call out to the IDP and authenticate the user, getting all of the roles and permissions via claims, as well as an access token to continue to use AppApi and all of the glorious resources it is the gate-keeper for.

Now, the part I'm a little stuck on is how I access CommonApi after the user has already been authenticated. I already have an access token (likely JWT) from the IDP and all of the roles and permissions as well. I'll need to check if AppApi is *allowed* to access CommonApi, but I also want to have to check the database with every call to CommonApi or make another call to the IDP, if it's avoidable.

Should there be a second token to access CommonApi? I would like to avoid that if possible, but if that's the best way, that's what I'll do. I'm not looking for the tech-specific solution -- libraries, middleware, etc., but an understanding of *what* I should be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just looking at things from the wrong perspective. The right perspective should clear up your confusion.

The fact that some other API is accessing your API is inconsequential. At the end of the day, your API serves *clients*, and all you need to know is some client is accessing your API. That could be another API, a user, a console app, a service, whatever. Doesn't matter.

That client needs to be authorized to use your application. The method of authentication to become authorized can vary based on the client but it all achieves the same goal. For example, something like another API will very likely auth via client authentication (an id/key pair). Here, you're authorizing the *client*, so if that client is acting on behalf of a particular user, they would separately need to authenticate as that user (typically via OAuth). Alternatively, if the other API exclusively works for a particular user, the whole thing can simply be achieved via OAuth (i.e. the client itself does not authenticate, but rather users of that client authenticate via an OAuth workflow presented by the client. In either case, the client ends up with an auth token that they can then send with further requests to authorize the request.

The important part is that auth token. No matter what the method of authentication, an auth token will be given, and *that* is what is used to authorize requests.

Based on the scenario you've presented here. The most likely course is that `AppApi` should authenticate with `CommonApi` via client authentication (it would be assigned a client id and a client secret and would send that to an endpoint on `CommonApi` to get an access token. It would then authorize all requests to `CommonApi` with *that* access token. The user of the website would authenticate with that website and interact with `AppApi` based on that authentication, but that should have no bearing on anything that happens with `CommonApi`. The one exception would be if `AppApi` is *impersonating* the user for `CommonApi`. For example, I might have an API that does some stuff on Facebook. If I need to do something like post as a particular user via that API, then the user needs to directly authenticate with Facebook via an OAuth workflow with that API. Afterwards, the API is granted an access token to do things on the user's behalf.

Comment: So, in your scenario, would there be an access token between the SPA and its own API (AppApi), retrieved from the IDP? Then, it would have an access token to be used between AppApi and CommonApi, which would be retrieved from the IDP _after_ the client authentication between AppApi and CommonApi using the client_id, client_secret? Did I follow that correctly?